# Open an identical browser window using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser

The title says it all. I want, using JavaScript, to open a window where everything in that window is exactly the same. The same DOM objects, the same JS variables, everything, except they're deep clones, so that changing them doesn't modify the original window.

Can this be done?

Comment: I'm aware that this is probably impossible. I've spent the past day trying to do this and finding nothing. But I figure others must have tried.

Comment: What do you mean by identical windows?

Comment: @Nithin- As in, a window that contains identical DOM elements and JavaScript. Not just pointers to the original, but new instances with all the same information.

Comment: Should a change in one window be reflected in an other? Also what is the content in the main window and how is it fetched or computed?

Comment: No to the first question. The content is generated with JavaScript, but really I'm looking for something that just takes everything- all the JS and HTML and stuff- and replicates it exactly.

Comment: You can use `window.open(window.location.href)` right? If another window itself is needed  `window.open(window.location.href, "_blank", 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')`

Comment: Yes, but that opens a blank window. I'm talking about a window that replicates everything from the original.

Comment: Can you host the code on netlify or share the code so that i can have a look? Even something bare minimum w/o all the details will do.

Comment: The only place I have to start from is window.open. If I modify a variable from what is sent from the server, then open a window to the current URL, that variable will be at the initial state. If I have a large, complex page that I want to completely replicate, I have no way of programmatically taking the entire state at once. If I try to do a deep clone of everything, that copies across references to page elements on the original page.

My hope is that there's something in the browser itself that will allow me to just say I want the current page replicated in its entirety.

Comment: By what i am understanding the only way to do it is, save all the details of a page into a variable and send that across an API to an endpoint capable of resolving the values to replicate or clone the same page. If you're using React and have all the values in your state then you can simply send it as a header to the same page and on `componentDidMount()` check if the header exists and then `setState()` else if using normal `JavaScript` copy all the values to an `JSON` Object and send it across as a header param after stringifying it and do the same on `window.load()`

Comment: Do note that it may pose cross browser issues but can be resolved.

Comment: I literally just want something that clones a browser window. I don't want to do it manually. If it can't be done, that's fine. If you don't know, that's also fine. I'm okay with leaving this open.